# Using ms-appdata:///Local/ In Adaptive Cards

Tags: c#, uwp, adaptive-cards

I have been using adaptive cards in the Windows 10 timeline and up to now have been getting the `backgroundImage` from a URL which works fine. I would like to know if it is possible to switch to using a local image stored in the `LocalStorage` folder of my UWP app but when I change the `backgroundImage` to `ms-appdata:///Local/Card.jpeg` the image does not display and the file is 100% in the directory as it is used fine in the application itself.

Anyone have any ideas and managed to get this working using `ms-appdata`?

Comment: check properties of image in vs, is it set as content and copy to output directory

Comment: Could you please post the source code of how you are constructing the card? Next, try changing the extension from `jpeg` to `jpg`. Could you also try using `local` instead of `Local`? Finally, could you post a screenshot of the `ApplicationData.Local` folder so that we see the image there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Timeline `UserActivities` must be HTTP images today. A primary function of `UserActivities` is to roam across devices, and there is no guarantee that a given app (and its associated local images) would be available on a device. As an example, Microsoft Launcher recently [added support for Timeline](https://www.engadget.com/2018/10/02/microsoft-launcher-android-timeline-whatsapp/).

The Adaptive Cards team is looking to improve this situation by adding support for "[data-URIs](https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/628)", which are base64 encoded images directly in the payload. This feature is being implemented now but won't roll out to Timeline until a future release of Windows. Please let us know if this addresses your needs or post any other suggestions on the team's GitHub.

Comment: Thank you, I was starting to think this might be the case especially with the cross platform features you mentioned. Sounds like the data-URls with help this - looking forward to this getting implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it as well.  Adaptive cards don't work with ms-appdata:///